# Highmaps Graphics with Laravel5

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Good morning ! I am preparing my database for use HighMaps with Laravel5, I receive this JSON form since Laravel.

```
[{"hc-key":"es-vi"},{"hc-key":"es-cs"},{"hc-key":"es-lo"},{"hc-key":"es-z"}]
```

Higchamps needs the following format:

```
 var data = [{ 'hc-key': 'es-pm', value: 0 },
                { 'hc-key': 'es-va', value: 1 },
                { 'hc-key': '', value: 52 }];
```

How could I send the format data that Highmaps need?

The sql in controller is this:

```
$provincias= DB::table('provincia')->lists('hc-key');
```

Comment: Please, post the Laravel code that generates this result, so we can understand the scenario.

Comment: I put the code in controller but the sep I don't know to pass is the foreach into variable data.

Comment: i am not sure but `array_combine` might come handy if you get/create another array of indexes.

Comment: And example of this , I don't know how to convert this json to varibale of javascript.

Comment: I've posted a possible answer, but also wanted to say that it appears as though you're missing a comma in your first code snippet above between "es-cs"} and {"hc-key" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I'm not really sure where you would get the "values" you speak of, and, I'm assuming you know where those values come from, the easiest way I can come up with quickly is to use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

```
$data = '[{"hc-key":"es-vi"},{"hc-key":"es-cs"},{"hc-key":"es-lo"},{"hc-key":"es-z"}]';
$data = json_decode($data);
foreach ($data as $item) {
    if ($item->{'hc-key'} == 'your_key_here') {
        $item->value = 'your_numeric_value_here';
    }
}
$data = json_encode($data);
```